# Error: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '' because '' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel, .net-6.0

I want to render data to view from the model which consists of list.

Transaction Model:

```cs
public class Transaction
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

TransactionViewModel:

```cs
public class TransactionViewModel
{
    public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
   // var dataset = new DataSet();
    using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
    connection.Open();

    /* getting account name, type, date, amount from transaction and account table*/
    var sql = @"SELECT *
                    FROM account as a
                         INNER JOIN transaction AS t
                         ON a.account_id = t.account_id";

    using var sqlCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection);
    NpgsqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
    List<Transaction> transaction_Lists = new List<Transaction>();

    if (reader.HasRows)

    {

        while (reader.Read())

        {

            transaction_Lists.Add(new Transaction

            {

                AccountId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["account_id"]),

                AccountName = Convert.ToString(reader["account_name"]),

                Type = Convert.ToString(reader["type"]),

                Amount = Convert.ToInt32(reader["amount"]),


            });

        }

    }

    return View(transaction_Lists);
}
```

View:

```cs
@using System.Data;
@model MyViewModel;

            @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.AccountName</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

In the view I am getting an error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '' because '' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

Why I cannot loop through this?

Comment: No way to know as you did not post code of `MyViewModel` (which is very likely not enumerable). Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your help, `    public class TransactionViewModel
    {
        public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    }`

Answer (score 1):

From your `Index()`, you are trying to return View Model as `List<Transaction>` type.

Change your View as below:

```
@model List<Transaction>

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.AccountName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

[Sample MVC (`List<Transaction>` model)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cqptPF)

---

Or if you want to return the View Model as `TransactionViewModel` type.

> Controller

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
   ...

    var model = new TransactionViewModel();
    model.Transactions = transaction_Lists;
            
    return View(model);
}
```

> View

```
@model TransactionViewModel

@foreach(var item in Model.Transactions)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.AccountName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

[Sample MVC (`TransactionViewModel` model)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/A7zOoY)

Comment: thanks for your help, but I have an issue
but I have an issue in the controller, I am getting errors:
'Transaction' does not contain a definition for 'TransactionId'

can you please help me?

Comment: Your `Transaction` class doesn't contain a property named 'TransactionId'. Make sure you add this property into class.